# Is it possible to compile all libraries like NLTK,Docx,PYPDF2 into Kivy through APK?

Tags: python, kivy, nltk

good day everyone, we are currently building a android application in python using kivy, with nltk, pypdf2, and docx libraries. After we converted into .apk and installed in mobile, when we open the application the application keep crashing after loading screen. Did i forget something?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: first try, next ask question.